# Error :Could not load file or assembly 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml,

Tags: c#, mysql, email

I'm getting this error is VS2015

> Additional information: Could not load file or assembly
>   'DocumentFormat.OpenXml, Version=2.5.5631.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The
>   located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly
>   reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

I am trying to send mail with database table attachment in c#

here my code id

```
using ClosedXML.Excel;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;
using System.Net.Mail;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Email
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        String MyConString = "SERVER=10.0.30.125;" + "DATABASE=test;" + "UID=root;" + "PASSWORD=asterisk;" + "Convert Zero Datetime = True";        
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = GetData();
            dt.TableName = "data";
            using (XLWorkbook wb = new XLWorkbook())
            {
                wb.Worksheets.Add(dt);
                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    wb.SaveAs(memoryStream);
                    byte[] bytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                    memoryStream.Close();
                    using (MailMessage Msg = new MailMessage())
                    {
                        Msg.From = new MailAddress("my@mail.com");
                        Msg.To.Add("to@mail.com");
                        Msg.Subject = "DATA";
                        Msg.Body = "Excel Attachment";
                        Msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(new MemoryStream(bytes), "DATA.xlsx"));
                        Msg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                        SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient();
                        smtp.Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
                        smtp.EnableSsl = true;
                        System.Net.NetworkCredential credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential();
                        credentials.UserName = "my@mail.com";
                        credentials.Password = "password";
                        smtp.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
                        smtp.Credentials = credentials;
                        smtp.Port = 587;
                        smtp.Send(Msg);
                        MessageBox.Show("MAIL SENT SUCCESSFULLY TO " + txtTo.Text);
                        txtTo.Text = "";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        private DataTable GetData()
        {
            using (MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection(MyConString))
            {
                using (MySqlCommand cmd = new MySqlCommand("SELECT * from table;", conn))
                using (MySqlDataAdapter sda = new MySqlDataAdapter())
                {
                    cmd.Connection = conn;
                    sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
                    using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                    {
                        sda.Fill(dt);
                        return dt;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I add it in my AddReference

```
ClosedXml.dll
DocumentFormat.OpenXml.dll
MySql.Data.dll
```

Help to solve my problem . why i m getting this error?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download And Install DocumentFormat.OpenXml version 2.5 [https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425](http://DocumentFormat.OpenXml)

Comment: This link now appears to be dead. It is available in NuGet however.

Comment: Copy the link and paste it to the browser. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30425